# Unir 2 consultas para mostrar un resultado calculado (división entre campos) SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Este sp me calcula registros y me entrega los siguientes datos:

```
USE [PRM]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_telemetria_safety_mensual]    Script Date: 21/03/2017 02:28:34 p. m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_telemetria_camiones_promedio_sobrerevolucion_mensual] (@Mes varchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @tmpMeses as table ( Mes varchar(50), cMes varchar(2) )
        insert @tmpMeses 
        select * from (
        select 'Enero' Mes, '01' cMes
            union
        select 'Febrero' Mes, '02' cMes
            union
        select 'Marzo' Mes, '03' cMes
            union
        select 'Abril' Mes, '04' cMes
            union
        select 'Mayo' Mes, '05' cMes
            union
        select 'Junio' Mes, '06' cMes
            union
        select 'Julio' Mes, '07' cMes
            union
        select 'Agosto' Mes, '08' cMes
            union
        select 'Septiembre' Mes, '09' cMes
            union
        select 'Octubre' Mes, '10' cMes
            union
        select 'Noviembre' Mes, '11' cMes
            union
        select 'Diciembre' Mes, '12' cMes
        ) Meses

        declare @FI datetime , @FF datetime
        declare @cMes varchar(50)  

        select @cMes = cMes from @tmpMeses  where Mes = @Mes 

        declare @MesAct varchar(2), @strCadenaMes varchar(50)
        select @MesAct = case when month(Fleet.dbo.fnGetDateLocal()) <10 then '0' + month(Fleet.dbo.fnGetDateLocal()) else cast(month(Fleet.dbo.fnGetDateLocal()) as varchar(2)) end

        print @Mes
        print @MesAct

        IF cast(@cMes as int)> cast(@MesAct as int)
            select @FI = '2016-' + @cMes + '-' + '01' , @strCadenaMes = @Mes + ' 2016' 
        ELSE 
            select @FI = '2017-' + @cMes + '-' + '01' , @strCadenaMes = @Mes + ' 2017'   

        select @FF = DATEADD( Day, -1,  DATEADD( Month, 1 , @FI ) ) 

        print @FI
        print @FF

        -- Insert statements for procedure here
        ---semanal cuenta numero economico
        declare @FechasSemanas as table (
                SemanaAño int, 
                Semana varchar(50), 
                FechaInicio varchar(10), 
                FechaFin varchar(10), 
                FangoFechas varchar(40))
        insert @FechasSemanas 

        exec PRM.dbo.prm_spFEMSA_SemanasIndicadoresTelemetria

        select @FI=Min(FechaInicio) , @FF=max(FechaInicio) from @FechasSemanas where Semana like  @strCadenaMes + '%'

        --print @FI
        --print @FF

        --declare @FI date= '2016-11-27' ---'2016-12-01'  
        --declare @FF date = '2016-12-25' ---DATEADD( Day, -1,  DATEADD( Month, 1 , @FI ) ) 


         --PROMEDIO DE EVENTOS, TABLA 1
         ;with tmpSemanas as (
             select i.CeEmplazamiento, i.FechaInicio, -- s.Semana, 
                    sum(i.RPMEventos) as Totales
                 from prm_FEMSA_IndicadoresTelemetria as i with(nolock)
                    --inner join @FechasSemanas s on 
                        --  i.FechaInicio = s.FechaInicio and
                            --i.FechaFin = s.FechaFin
                 where i.FechaInicio between @FI and @FF
                       and i.AccountId = 9159
                       and CeEmplazamiento <> '3BKHHM8X2CF378241'
                group by i.CeEmplazamiento, i.FechaInicio --s.Semana

         )   

         select s.CeEmplazamiento, sum(s.Totales) as Totales
            from tmpSemanas s
            cross join (
                        select sum(Totales) TotGral 
                            from tmpSemanas s2 
                            where Totales > 0
                        ) s2
            group by s.CeEmplazamiento, s2.TotGral              
            --order by CeEmplazamiento asc


        --//////////////////////
        --PROMEDIO DE UNIDADES, TABLA 2
        ;with tmpSemanas_2 as(
            select i.CeEmplazamiento, i.FechaInicio, count(i.NoEconomico) as Totales
                 from prm_FEMSA_IndicadoresTelemetria as i with(nolock)                 
                 where i.FechaInicio between @FI and @FF and RPMEventos > 0
                       and i.AccountId = 9159
                       and CeEmplazamiento <> '3BKHHM8X2CF378241'
                group by i.CeEmplazamiento, i.FechaInicio
         )

         select s.CeEmplazamiento, avg(s.Totales) Totales
            from tmpSemanas_2 s
            cross join (
                        select avg(Totales) TotGral 
                            from tmpSemanas_2 s2 
                            where Totales > 0
                        ) s2
            group by s.CeEmplazamiento, s2.TotGral      


        --/////////////////------------------------ 

end


Tabla 1
CeEmplazamiento Totales
Celaya            1059
Coecillo           534
Irapuato          1789
León Sur           415
Los Reyes           0
Oriente León       577


Tabla 2
CeEmplazamiento Totales
    Celaya        20
    Coecillo      25
    Irapuato      38
    León Sur      10
    Oriente León  33
```

Me gustaria hacer el calculo de dividir el resultado de la primera con la segunda es decir, mi resultado me quedaria de la siguiente forma:

```
CeEmplazamiento Totales
Celaya           52.95
Coecillo         21.36
Irapuato         47.07894737
León Sur         41.5
Oriente León    17.48484848
```

Alguién sabe como hacerlo, sé que es mediante el UNION. Gracias a todos.

Comment: Hola Ric_hc, recuerda poner las etiquetas de las tecnologías que usas, por ejemplo MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle etc. esto nos puede ayudar determinar una mejor respuesta a tu problema sin caer en especulaciones.

Comment: Uff, lo siento, creí que la habia agregado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muchas gracias a todos, lo resolví de la siguiente manera, dividi todas las subconsultas en tablas y de ahí hice un join de las tablas finales. Les agrego todo el código de como quedo ya con el resultado calculado. Agradezco a todos sus respuestas. Saludos

```
USE [PRM]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_telemetria_safety_mensual]    Script Date: 21/03/2017 02:28:34 p. m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>

    -- =============================================
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_telemetria_camiones_promedio_sobrerevolucion_mensual] (@Mes varchar(50))
    AS
    BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        declare @tmpMeses as table ( Mes varchar(50), cMes varchar(2) )
            insert @tmpMeses 
            select * from (
            select 'Enero' Mes, '01' cMes
                union
            select 'Febrero' Mes, '02' cMes
                union
            select 'Marzo' Mes, '03' cMes
                union
            select 'Abril' Mes, '04' cMes
                union
            select 'Mayo' Mes, '05' cMes
                union
            select 'Junio' Mes, '06' cMes
                union
            select 'Julio' Mes, '07' cMes
                union
            select 'Agosto' Mes, '08' cMes
                union
            select 'Septiembre' Mes, '09' cMes
                union
            select 'Octubre' Mes, '10' cMes
                union
            select 'Noviembre' Mes, '11' cMes
                union
            select 'Diciembre' Mes, '12' cMes
            ) Meses

            declare @FI datetime , @FF datetime
            declare @cMes varchar(50)  

            select @cMes = cMes from @tmpMeses  where Mes = @Mes 

            declare @MesAct varchar(2), @strCadenaMes varchar(50)
            select @MesAct = case when month(Fleet.dbo.fnGetDateLocal()) <10 then '0' + month(Fleet.dbo.fnGetDateLocal()) else cast(month(Fleet.dbo.fnGetDateLocal()) as varchar(2)) end

            print @Mes
            print @MesAct

            IF cast(@cMes as int)> cast(@MesAct as int)
                select @FI = '2016-' + @cMes + '-' + '01' , @strCadenaMes = @Mes + ' 2016' 
            ELSE 
                select @FI = '2017-' + @cMes + '-' + '01' , @strCadenaMes = @Mes + ' 2017'   

            select @FF = DATEADD( Day, -1,  DATEADD( Month, 1 , @FI ) ) 

            print @FI
            print @FF

            -- Insert statements for procedure here
            ---semanal cuenta numero economico
            declare @FechasSemanas as table (
                    SemanaAño int, 
                    Semana varchar(50), 
                    FechaInicio varchar(10), 
                    FechaFin varchar(10), 
                    FangoFechas varchar(40))
            insert @FechasSemanas 

            exec PRM.dbo.prm_spFEMSA_SemanasIndicadoresTelemetria

            select @FI=Min(FechaInicio) , @FF=max(FechaInicio) from @FechasSemanas where Semana like  @strCadenaMes + '%'

            --print @FI
            --print @FF

            --declare @FI date= '2016-11-27' ---'2016-12-01'  
            --declare @FF date = '2016-12-25' ---DATEADD( Day, -1,  DATEADD( Month, 1 , @FI ) ) 


             --PROMEDIO DE EVENTOS, TABLA 1

             ;with tmpSemanas as (
                 select i.CeEmplazamiento, i.FechaInicio, -- s.Semana, 
                        sum(i.RPMEventos) as Totales
                     from prm_FEMSA_IndicadoresTelemetria as i with(nolock)
                        --inner join @FechasSemanas s on 
                            --  i.FechaInicio = s.FechaInicio and
                                --i.FechaFin = s.FechaFin
                     where i.FechaInicio between @FI and @FF
                           and i.AccountId = 9159
                           and CeEmplazamiento <> '3BKHHM8X2CF378241'
                    group by i.CeEmplazamiento, i.FechaInicio --s.Semana

             ), promedio_eventos as (

                     select s.CeEmplazamiento, sum(s.Totales) as Totales
                        from tmpSemanas s
                        cross join (
                                    select sum(Totales) TotGral 
                                        from tmpSemanas s2 
                                        where Totales > 0
                                    ) s2
                        group by s.CeEmplazamiento, s2.TotGral
            )
                        --order by CeEmplazamiento asc


            --//////////////////////
            --PROMEDIO DE UNIDADES, TABLA 2
            --;with tmpSemanas_2 as(
            , tmpSemanas_2 as
                (
                select i.CeEmplazamiento, i.FechaInicio, count(i.NoEconomico) as Totales
                     from prm_FEMSA_IndicadoresTelemetria as i with(nolock)                 
                     where i.FechaInicio between @FI and @FF and RPMEventos > 0
                           and i.AccountId = 9159
                           and CeEmplazamiento <> '3BKHHM8X2CF378241'
                    group by i.CeEmplazamiento, i.FechaInicio
             )

             , promedio_unidades as (    

                     select s.CeEmplazamiento, avg(s.Totales) Totales
                        from tmpSemanas_2 s
                        cross join (
                                    select avg(Totales) TotGral 
                                        from tmpSemanas_2 s2 
                                        where Totales > 0
                                    ) s3
                        group by s.CeEmplazamiento, s3.TotGral          
                )   


            --//consulta final calculada
            select 
                    a.CeEmplazamiento  as CeEmplazamiento

                    ,case when isnull(b.Totales,0) = 0 then a.Totales
                         else a.Totales/isnull(b.Totales,0) end as Totales

                    --,a.Totales / b.Totales as Totales
                from promedio_eventos a 
                        inner join promedio_unidades b on
                                a.CeEmplazamiento = b.CeEmplazamiento

    end




CeEmplazamiento   Totales
Celaya             52
Coecillo           21
Irapuato           47
León Sur           41
Oriente León       17
```

Answer (score 1):

Mira hice un pequeño ejemplo, lo resolví con un join:

```
DECLARE @Tabla1 TABLE
(
  CeEmplazamiento nvarchar(max), 
  Totales money
)
insert into @Tabla1 select 'Celaya',1059
insert into @Tabla1 select 'Coecillo',534
insert into @Tabla1 select 'Irapuato',1789
insert into @Tabla1 select 'León Sur',415
insert into @Tabla1 select 'Los Reyes',0
insert into @Tabla1 select 'Oriente León',577


DECLARE @Tabla2 TABLE
(
  CeEmplazamiento nvarchar(max), 
  Totales money
)
insert into @Tabla2 select 'Celaya',20
insert into @Tabla2 select 'Coecillo',25
insert into @Tabla2 select 'Irapuato',38
insert into @Tabla2 select 'León Sur',10
insert into @Tabla2 select 'Oriente León',33


select 
    --t1.*,t2.*
    t1.CeEmplazamiento
    --,t1.Totales tabla1
    --,isnull(t2.Totales,0) tabla2
    ,case when isnull(t2.Totales,0) = 0 then t1.Totales
    else t1.Totales/isnull(t2.Totales,0) end as Total
from @Tabla1 t1
    left join   @Tabla2 t2
    on t1.CeEmplazamiento = t2.CeEmplazamiento
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

puedes cambiar esta linea:

```
left join   @Tabla2 t2
```

por un `inner`

```
inner join   @Tabla2 t2
```

y así solo se mostrarán los que existan en ambas tablas.

Si tienes dudas con mucho gusto te respondo.  Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Si los resultados quedan en tablas temporales (`@tabla` o `#tabla`) puedes hacer un inner join.

```
select 
    t1.Ciudad,
    t1.Totales/ t2.Totales
from
    @tabla1 t1
inner join
    @tabla2 t2
    on
        t2.Ciudad = t1.Ciudad
```

Si no son tablas temporales, la consulta que arroja esos resultados, puedes agruparlos como subconsulta y hacer el `inner join`.

```
select 
    t1.Ciudad,
    t1.Totales/ t2.Totales
from
    (
        select
            Ciudad,
            Totales
        from
            TuTablas
    ) as t1
inner join
    (
        select
            Ciudad,
            Totales
        from
            TuTablas
    ) as t2
    on
        t2.Ciudad = t1.Ciudad
```

Espero me haya explicado y sea de ayuda.